# How can I fix my fonts being unreadable in Java and Flash applications?

Tags: windows-xp, fonts, java, flash

I have been seeing this in a Java application that wasn't present earlier.

I had done something with the smooth fonts utility provided by Windows XP, which could be the source of the problem. So I have tried uninstalling the smooth fonts utility from  Power Toys. But I ca'nt remember exactly after which event the fonts started getting garbled in Java applications

I have again seen it today in a Flash applications, for which I have captured the screenshot below. One thing I notice is that the fonts are garbled when on dark backgrounds, while in the Java application, the fonts are clear when on white backgrounds, but when selected become garbled because the background changes to black.

[image: this is fom a flash app in a webpage in chrome browser]

What is the source of this problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tool in question is [ClearType Tuner](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartypepowertoy.mspx) from the Windows XP PowerToys, then uninstalling it does not change anything. The tool modifies the way text is displayed throughout the system, and the change is "from now on".

I suggest to reinstall the tool, then do two tests - turning ClearType on and off, and seeing whether the results are better with or without it.